# Android SlidingTabLayout issue

Tags: android

Can anybody help please? My app stops running whenever I copy and paste the following code in my activity_main.xml

```
<samples.exoguru.materialtabs.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>
```

I copied it from [this source](http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html).

Comment: You can write down the error that appears in your log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **TabLayout** from **android.support.design**

More details - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

Or this article - https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout